# Простейшее объединение таблиц и serialize();

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Товарищи,в MySQL абсолютно нет опыта, подскажите **запрос** как объединить эти таблицы: [image]

Чтобы исход получился как строка красным. И ещё вопрос:

- Что будет если catid из первой таблицы будет отсутствовать во второй (было бы идеально вернуть полностью пустой ответ)?
- Использую PHP serialize(); для некоторых данных который не нуждающихся в сортировке, приемлемо ли это для хранения в базе? какой тип данных mysql выбрать для ячейки с serialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте **LEFT JOIN**

Что-то должно получится вроде этого:

```
 SELECT 
    `items`.`id`, `items`.`isshow`, `items`.`art`, `items`.`name`, `items`.`model`, `items`.`catid`,
    `cats`.`name`, `cats`.`offer`
    FROM `items`
    LEFT JOIN `cats`
    ON `items`.`catid`=`cats`.`catid`
where `items`.`id` = 1
```

Результат:

[image]

> Что будет если catid из первой таблицы будет отсутствовать во второй (было бы идеально вернуть полностью пустой ответ)?

Тогда будет сложнее =) Это как бы то, что их объединяет. Можно как вариант создать отдельную таблицу - контейнер и там их связывать. Это уже от задачи зависит.
 Или если id  в таблице cats  тоже самое, что catid, то catid здесь бессмысленно. Просто связывайте по id

```
LEFT JOIN `cats` ON `items`.`catid`=`cats`.`id`
```